# jqgrid via Perl

Tags: perl, jqgrid

I'm trying to send JSON information to jqgrid via Perl, however I'm struggling on how to get the appropriate JSON structure:

Per JQgrid docs, the JSON needs to be in the following format:

> ```
> {
> "total": "xxx",
> "page": "yyy",
> "records": "zzz",
> "rows" : [
> {"id" :"1", "cell" :["cell11", "cell12", "cell13"]},
> {"id" :"2", "cell":["cell21", "cell22", "cell23"]},
> ...
> ]
> }
> ```

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use CGI (-debug);
use DBI;
use JSON;
use POSIX qw(ceil);
use strict;
use warnings;
...
my $i=0;
my $response = {};
$response->{total} = $total_pages;
$response->{page} = $page;
$response->{records} = $count;
while ( my $row = $sth->fetchrow_hashref ){
        $response->{rows}->[$i]->{id} = $i;
        $response->{rows}->[$i]->{cell} = ($row);
        $i++;
}
print $cgi->header(-type => "application/json", -charset => "utf-8");
print JSON::to_json($response);
```

I'm pretty sure I need a hash of arrays, but I can't seem to figure out how to go about it.

Comment: Try `$response->{rows}->[0]->{id} = $id; $response->{rows}->[0]->{cell} = $cell_array_ref;` Also you have a wrong `header`for the JSON...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one problem:

```
$response->{rows}->[id]
```

In that phrase you're taking a hashref (`$response`), accessing its hash key "`rows`", and then accessing an anonymous array referred to by `$response->{rows}`.  So far so good, but the anonymous array cannot have an element named '`id`', unless '`id`' is defined somewhere as a constant, which I don't see anywhere in the code you posted.  It's more likely that you mean "`$response->{rows}{id}`".  In other words, a hash of hashes.  Note, the `->` operator is redundant when sandwiched between indices, so I removed it.

However, you mentioned in your post that you need a hash of arrays.  But that would have to look more like `$response->{rows}[0]`.

One thing I find useful sometimes is to just use Data::Dumper to dump the return value of fetchrow_hashref to see what it looks like.  You may already have a picture of it in your mind, but sometimes seeing it dumped out as a datastructure will help you to better visualize how your datastructure should be rearranged to fit the design requirements.